# How to remove the labels on my post (DIFFERENT LABEL)

Tags: label, blogger

How can i remove this type of labels on my posts. Or how could i change it into Home/Software/FL Studio. THANKS!

Home / android / full / modified / no root / paid / patch / signed / FL Studio Mobile v3.2.20 [Full/Unlocked+Patched]

This is my site visit it... https://www.peleis.ml/fl-studio-mobile-3.2.20

Comment: What do u mean?

Comment: how to get it ? an xml file?

Comment: Thanks but is there anyway to hide it or change?

Comment: But really how? i dont understand what your saying